# Exemption of a specific policy from an initiative using terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I need help regarding below

Is there any way to exempt a specific policy from an initiative using terraform in azure.

pls do respond if anyone have any solution for this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Policy exemptions (preview) feature is used to exempt a resource hierarchy or an individual resource from evaluation of initiatives or definitions.Two exemption categories exist and are used to group exemptions:

**1.Mitigated. 2.Waiver**

Using `policy-exemptions` ie Terraform module for managing AzureRM policy exemptions (via ARM template).

You can refer this ***[document](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/globalbao/policy-exemptions/azurerm/latest)*** there are various example of `policy-extemption` for specic resources in RG and Target targeting resources in 2 RGs in 2 subscriptions

Comment: Thank You so Much. Our issue was resolved by following this :)

Answer (score 1):

Support for this feature was added with the v3.2.0 version of the AzureRm Terraform provider which came out in April this year : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_policy_exemption.

Sample code:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_policy_exemption" "example" {
  name                 = "exemption1"
  resource_id          = azurerm_resource_policy_assignment.example.resource_id
  policy_assignment_id = azurerm_resource_policy_assignment.example.id
  exemption_category   = "Mitigated"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the present in Terraform you can specific the policies you want to exempt in an initiative with the property «policy_definition_reference_ids» in the «azurerm_management_group_policy_exemption».

```
resource "azurerm_management_group_policy_exemption" "example" {
  name                 = "exemption1"
  management_group_id  = azurerm_management_group.example.id
  policy_assignment_id = azurerm_management_group_policy_assignment.example.id
  exemption_category   = "Mitigated"
  policy_definition_reference_ids = [
    "Name of the first policy to exempt",
    "Name of the second policy to exempt"
  ]
}
```

For more information: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/management_group_policy_exemption